# Resampling raster with rectangular pixels

Tags: qgis, resampling

I have a raster file of deforestation but the pixeles are not square. When I project the raster the information of it says that the pixel size is 0.000275322,-0.000271395. I would like to resample the raster such that I have square pixels that have a size of, for example, 0.0025, -0.0025. I want to make this so that I can match the information of the deforestation raster with a slope raster which cells size is 0.0025, -0.0025.

I have not been able to create rasters with non-square pixels (that might also be a solution).

Comment: Use Layer- Save as and define the horizontal and vertical resolutions as you wish.

Comment: thanks! This works. But I don't really understand what the QGIS is doing, so I want to make sure I am doing it correctly. My raster has only three values (1, 2 ,3). does QGIS uses Nearest Neighbor as undelying resample method? I understand that NN is the best method when dealing with rasters such as mine.